# iterate by using loops for template variables in magento

Tags: email

```
$quoteItems=array();
foreach($quotecollection as $value)
{                                           
$quoteItems[] = $value['name'];
}. 
$vars['articledescription'] = $value['name'];.
```

I have used the above code for email template.
I want the product name to be iterated through loops , when there are multiple products ordered by customers.
pls suggest with code

Comment: Please keep in mind that order and quote are not the same

Comment: is this the same question as https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/59069/using-foreach-in-order-email-template-magento ??