# using foreach in order email template magento

Tags: magento-1.8

how to print all the product names in order email magento, when customers add more than one product.
how to achieve using for each loop for email template variable
I have tried as below :

```
foreach($quotecollection as $value){                                            
    $quoteItems[] = $value['name'];                                 
}
```

Comment: Where do you want to print out this info?

Comment: In the order email template

Comment: see http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8602/is-there-a-way-to-add-foreach-loop-in-email-template